# Can you select a table value in a MySql Query and edit it?

Tags: mysql

For my MySQL query, I need to select a specific value like:

```
$query = "Select * from playerdata where name = $name"
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
```

However, I want to take that grabbed specific table value (the * operator) and then edit that one like so:

```
$newquery = "insert into [I want to insert some values from the 
             old query's selection] [not the general table]"
```

I know how to use queries and how to execute them. It would be great if I could condense both the select and the insert into one query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [SQL INSERT INTO SELECT Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

```
INSERT INTO table2
Select * from playerdata where name = 'Pedro';
```

To use this in your PHP script it would look something like this:

```
$nameSafe = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$newquery = "INSERT INTO table2
             Select * from playerdata where name = '$nameSafe';";
```

It's good to understand the aspects of security from early on and for that [PHP Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet) is a good read.

Comment: Hey sorry thanks for the answer, Im kinda a newbie at this.. now how would you add data to line where we found pedro..

Comment: hey sorry I meant editing a value not doing what you showed.. I needed to use a update table but thanks anyways!